# Format number with commas in .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have some js which is converting a div class's number through a daily exchange rate engine. It outputs correctly as it should and I am now trying to separate this number it outputs using jQuery and a function I found whilst doing some research. I am trying to feed the number to the function using a `.innerHTML` method. I have got the function to alert a converted number but I have multiple elements which this function should run for, so have used an `.each` function - this is where something isn't working. I get no alert so I think there is something wrong with the .each code.

Can anyone see anything that might be causing it?

The complete code is here:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openexchangerates/money.js/master/money.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="hello">
  2300
</div>

<div class="hello">
  52400
</div>




<script>

    function ReplaceNumberWithCommas(yourNumber) {
    //Seperates the components of the number
    var n= yourNumber.toString().split(".");
    //Comma-fies the first part
    n[0] = n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    //Combines the two sections
    return n.join(".");
}

    $(".hello").each(function() {

    var currentDiv = $(this);
    var currentPrice = currentDiv.text();

    var demo = function(data) {
    fx.rates = data.rates
    var rate = fx(currentPrice).from("GBP").to("USD");
    currentDiv.html("<div>"+currentPrice +"</div><div id='converted'> " +rate.toFixed(0)+"</div>");
        //alert("Product Costs" + rate.toFixed(4))

}
    $.getJSON("http://api.fixer.io/latest", demo);
});


    $("#converted").each(function() {
        var convertedPrice = $(this.innerHTML);
        function runThis() { alert( ReplaceNumberWithCommas(convertedPrice)) }
        setTimeout (runThis, 100);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: I've tried that but got nowhere...    `$("#converted").each(function() {
        var convertedPrice = $(this.innerHTML);
        alert(convertedPrice.toLocaleString());
    });`

Comment: @Teemu also tried this `$("#converted").each(function() {
        var convertedPrice = $(this);
        convertedPrice.innertext.toLocaleString;`

Comment: might be a long shot, but where is fx defined?

Comment: externally it's a JS library for currency conversion...

Comment: could I call the locale string on this line? `currentDiv.html("<div>"+currentPrice +"</div><div id='converted'> " +rate.toFixed(0)+"</div>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is

`$("#converted").each(function() {
        var convertedPrice = $(this.innerHTML);
        function runThis() { alert( ReplaceNumberWithCommas(convertedPrice)) }
        setTimeout (runThis, 100);
    });`

happends before you created the converted elements. Because you put the creation inside a get call.

I suggest you put this inside the callback of your get call.

Something like this

```
  function ReplaceNumberWithCommas(yourNumber) {
    //Seperates the components of the number
    var n = yourNumber.toString().split(".");
    //Comma-fies the first part
    n[0] = n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    //Combines the two sections
    return n.join(".");
  }
    var currentDiv = $(this);
    var currentPrice = currentDiv.text();

    var demo = function(data) {
      fx.rates = data.rates
      $(".hello").each(function() {
        var currentDiv = $(this);
        var currentPrice = currentDiv.text();
        var rate = fx(currentPrice).from("GBP").to("USD");
        currentDiv.html("<div>" + currentPrice + "</div><div class='converted'> " + rate.toFixed(0) + "</div>");
        //alert("Product Costs" + rate.toFixed(4))
      });

      $(".converted").each(function() {
        var convertedPrice = $(this).html();
        console.log(ReplaceNumberWithCommas(convertedPrice));
      });
    }    
  $.getJSON("https://api.fixer.io/latest", demo);
```

Comment: Ok so how would I go about putting this into the call back of the get call? Sorry I am new to JS...

Comment: @dwinnbrown not sure if I understand your code correctly, but are you planning to query that api.fixer.io/latest every 100 milliseconds?

Comment: No I would like to wait 100ms and then convert the content. It's a timeout not an interval so that should work shouldn't it? i also tried using .toLocaleString but that didn't work either...

Comment: I get object [object] as the alert and then it messes up the numbers that are being set out...

Comment: @dwinnbrown please try my updated version. I think you don't even need a timeout if you put everything inside the callback. You previous issue is probably the get request takes longer than your timeout period. Edit: aw.. it's the alert actually alerting the jquery object... do you want convertedPrice?

Comment: I just did try it. Is there any way I could separate the number with commas on this line? `currentDiv.html("<div>" + currentPrice + "</div><div id='converted'> " + rate.toFixed(0) + "</div>");`

Comment: @dwinnbrown just fixed the bug for displaying object

Comment: hmm works great for the first alert (number two) but for some reason with the second one, it shows the first number multiplied by 10 as opposed to adding commas into the last number.

Comment: would giving it a class instead help with that do you think? --EDIT-- adding a class made it work for the two alerts as it should but then it fired another two, multiplying it by 10 each time...

Comment: @dwinnbrown yeah, that could be the reason. Sorry I couldn't try access github and try myself. Just updated my answer code again.

Comment: @dwinnbrown are you sure you don't have other scripts interfering? how many ``.converted`` divs do you get?

Comment: @dwinnbrown My gut feels you still have your old timeout function somewhere. Otherwise I cannot think of any possibilities.

Comment: @dwinnbrown sorry I wasn't able to access pastebin in office. Just got home, and found the bug in your code. Basically you enclose the get call inside a loop. I'll update my answer to contain full code. Edit: Updated

Comment: @dwinnbrown fixed a bug. such a simple question got me so many low quality bugs. such a shame :(

Comment: Hmm. I found another js library to do the job but will mark your answer as correct as i believe it's now working